# Compatible systems of $l$-adic Galois representations as sheaves

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have a simple translation question:

Suppose we fix embeddings $\iota_l: \mathbb{Q} → \mathbb{Q}_l$ for every rational prime $l$, and take a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a number field $E$.

Let $\mathcal{R} = \{R_{l,\iota_l} : Gal(\mathbb{\bar{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) → GL(V ⊗_{\mathbb{Q},\iota_l} \mathbb{Q}_l)\}$ be a weakly compatible system of Galois representations.

Can we think of $\mathcal{R}$ as a certain kind of sheaf over Spec $\mathbb{Z}$? If yes, how would the properties of $\mathcal{R}$ being strictly compatible/pure/geometric be expressed in terms of properties of this sheaf?

Comment: There are conjectures that every compatible system is represented (in an appropriate sense) by a unique object in some motivic category but I don't think it makes sense to think of this category structure as interesting, precisely because of the "weak" adjective. Even if these conjectures were true, the category you get would be analogous to "the category of $X$-graded vector spaces with graded components isomorphic to the stalks of a sheaf" for $X$ a topological space. If you could somehow get rid of the adjective "weakly" (for example by using motives) then your question is more meaningful.